# Is it possible to have Antd Typography.Paragraph multi row as Menu title?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

How can i get multiple rows to work inside Antd Submenu? Only one row works fine, but as soon as i select multiple, ellipsis is not shown at all and text is still in one row.

```
   <SubMenu
          title={
            <Typography.Paragraph ellipsis={{ rows: 2, tooltip: { title: 'Long title', placement: 'right' } }}>
              {'Long title'}
            </Typography.Paragraph>
          }
        >
          {submenuItems}
          )}
        </SubMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You just need to use `style` and `lineBreak` css prop:

```
<Typography.Paragraph
  ellipsis={{
    rows: 2,
    tooltip: {
      title: "Long title",
      placement: "right"
    }
  }}
  style={{
    width: 100,
    lineBreak: "auto"
  }}
>
  A very very very long title that will break line into two or more rows
</Typography.Paragraph>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the result is the same. As soon as 'rows: 2' is applied, ellipsis dissapears and the content is still shown in one row.
https://codesandbox.io/s/inline-menu-antd-5-8-6-forked-542dk5

Answer (score 0):

Using the following css, everything looks as intended

```
.ellipsisWrapper {
  &.@{typography-prefix-cls} {
    margin-bottom: 0; // remove default margins
  }
  white-space: initial;
  line-height: 1.2;
}
```